# Timestamp & Date comparison in MySQL - ambiguous error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1052

this is a follow up to a question I got help with on here yesterday, but it's a slightly different issue - i'm trying to check if a mysql timestamp of a db record matches 7 days in the past (ignoring hours and seconds etc), but I'm getting a "Column 'import_date' in where clause is ambiguous", can anyone see the problem?

This is the date comparison:
Timestamp, e.g 2010-07-13 11:04:27

```
WHERE date_format( `import_date`, "%Y-%m-%d" ) =
    date_format( date_sub( now(), INTERVAL 11 DAY ), "%Y-%m-%d" )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your ambiguous error you must have 2 tables in the query both with an `import_date` column. You would need to use

```
WHERE date_format( `YourTableName`.`import_date`, "%Y-%m-%d" ) =
    date_format( date_sub( now(), INTERVAL 11 DAY ), "%Y-%m-%d" )
```

Just to add though that your query above will be inefficient as it is not [SARGABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable)

I'm not familiar enough with MySQL to know exactly what it's doing but definitely you will be better off rewriting it as

```
WHERE `YourTableName`.`import_date` = x
```

or

```
WHERE `YourTableName`.`import_date` between x and y
```

as appropriate